# postfix alias_maps - can it be a directory

Tags: centos, postfix, aliases

Hi I'd like to dynamically add users to postfix, using a php service I am writing, but I'd like to keep the `/etc/alias` mechanic, and I've decided the best way I can do this is make individual `user.cf` files each one with aliases in it. I don't want to `$ echo "bob    :bob" >> /etc/alias` I'm sure you sympathise

EG: in a directory like `/etc/alias/users/*`

What i'd love to be able to do is this:

```
 alias_maps = hash:/etc/alias/users/*
```

Is this possible? How can I configure postfix to allow me to make my own dir to look after this? I can then simply check for an occurrence of this file in php and remove/rewrite it easily then restart postfix to handle name changes / new user creation.

Answer (score 2):

[Postfix doesn't support this sort of behavior](http://www.postfix.org/DATABASE_README.html#types).

Ultimately you'll be better served by having postfix and your php service interacting with a mutual database, e.g. mariadb, OpenLDAP, postgres. Though I suppose of you don't need something that scales past a common host, [`sqlite`](http://www.postfix.org/sqlite_table.5.html) is appropriate.

Databases really are the best things for this. There are already common ways for php to interact, and they don't require postfix to be restarted (or reloaded).

Comment: yeah I deliberately don't want to do that - I've just created a single ancillary `hash:` file I called `/etc/alias/users` for PHP to use: and since every line I make in there has a unique username in it I can smoothly remove the lines with the username in it iteratively - it just takes more code.

shame this was omitted, it's the most sensible way of operating imho. incidentally I didn't just have to add `alias_maps`

I had to do `alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/etc/alias/users` and `alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/etc/alias/users`